# Code difference before ToList() Query

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, comparison, standards

What is the difference between this methods

```
public List<CollegeAddress> GetAllAddress()
{
    return collegeAppContext.CollegeAddresses.ToList().Where(x => x.StateId == 4);
}
```

and

```
public List<CollegeAddress> GetAllAddress()
{
    return collegeAppContext.CollegeAddresses.Where(x => x.StateId == 4).ToList();
}
```

Which one method is standard code? (*But my First Method threw a conversation  error* : )

And What's the difference?

Comment: The second one is corrent. First retrieve the collection, filter it and then cast it (in your example cast to list).

Comment: Please post the exact error message you're getting with the first one. They should provide exactly the same results, the difference being where the filtering is done.

Comment: The issue is as @Bill described below - ToList().Where() will return an IQueryable<>, instead of the expected List<>.

Answer (score 5):

In your first example, you're bringing ALL CollegeAddresses from the database and then filtering.

Your second example adds a `where` clause to your query, so it's filtered BEFORE it comes to your method.

EDIT: 
As for the error in the first method, it's because `Where` returns an `IQueryable` rather than a `List`. So, you have to add `ToList();` You should still use the second method, though.

Comment: Doh, sorry. It's because `Where` returns an `IQueryable` rather than a `List`. So, you have to add `ToList();` You should still use the second method, though.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the first example will return an IQueryable which will be evaluated when queried, and the second example will return an evaluated List

may I also suggest a change in the method signature:

```
public List<CollegeAddress> GetAddressesByState(int stateId)
{
    return collegeAppContext.CollegeAddresses.Where(x => x.StateId == stateId).ToList();
}
```